# How to set the same style for <li><a> and <input> button

Tags: html, css

I am making a row of buttons:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
  <li>
    <form ... method="post">
      <input class="Btn" type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
  </li>  
  <li>
    <form ... method="post">
    <input class="Btn" type="submit" value="Delete">
    </form>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Exit</a></li>
</ul>
```

using the css:

```
li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #09F;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #111;
}
.Btn {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #09F;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #111;
}
```

I have two problems:

a) The shape of `<a>` and `<input>` buttons are a little different and they are not perfectly aligned.

b) The font of the `<input>` buttons is different from that of `<a>`.

How can I make them look exactly the same and perfectly aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

your css should be like this.

```
    li,a,.Btn{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:35px;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin-right:5px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:35px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    background:white;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    font-family:'Arial';
    font-size:14px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.Btn{
    border:none;
}

li{
    border:1px solid;
}
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/obu63u80/

Answer (score 2):

Here, give this a try:

```
li {
  list-style: none;  
  display:inline;
  float:left;
}
.Btn,li a {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #09F;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #111;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:inline-block!important;
  border:none;
  line-height:18px;
  font-size:16px;
  margin-right:2px;
  font-family:Arial;  
  margin-top:0;
}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7gdzkc1v/1/

Comment: It looks fine in Chrome and Opera. But in Firefox, the height of `<input>` button is greater.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have firefox on this pc. Will have to test later

Comment: Correction: in Opera, the height of `<input>` is a little greater.

Comment: Don't have Opera either, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

you can add all the common attributes by adding `,` between two or more different classes

```
li a , .Btn {
   display: block;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: #09F;
   padding-top: 0.5em;
   padding-bottom: 0.5em;
   text-align: center;
   border-right: 1px solid #fff;
   color: #111;
}

.Btn {
   float: left;
   width: 100px;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<input>` and `<a>` use different font-families and different font-sizes.
Be sure to set these values so that your browser doesn't applies its default CSS.
Don't forget to set input margin to 0 and borders to none.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfgffkca/10/). These are the new styles which I've added:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #09F;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #111;
}
.Btn {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #09F;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #111;
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px 9px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

As far as the fonts are concerned, you need to define the font for the `<input>` tag and the `<a>` tag using the `font-family` property. Currently, the font for the `<a>` tag is Times New Roman and the font for the`<input>` tag is Arial.

[image]

Comment: Nope, the height of the `<input>` button is a little greater.

Comment: I just tested it in both Chrome and Firefox and the height of both the `<input>` button and the `<a>` are same i.e. 34px.

Comment: Is it due to the operation system? I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Please see the figure: http://www.cyut.edu.tw/~yltang/input.png

Comment: I believe so because the font of the `<input>` button and `<a>` tag appears quite different in your screenshot.

Comment: You can see here that how it appears inside Google Chrome on Windows 8: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EmPJF.jpg

Comment: Even if I set the default font and font size, 0 margin, 0 padding, and none border, the height of `<input>` is still greater. Maybe `padding: 10px 0px 9px 0px;` has to be `8px 0px 9px 0px;`

Comment: Yes, you can try reducing the padding since that's what controls the height of the `<input>` button.